# My professor send me an email that said I plagiarized and cheat

Tags: plagiarism, cheating

I am doing a closed and open book exam recently. I was working so hard on it and hoping to pass the exam. However, I received an email that said there’s an evidence that I plagiarized. I was crying for days and couldn’t do anything. I can’t even concentrate on reading and understanding the link they send to me. In the meeting, they shown me an evidence and what surprising to me was, one sentence that I wrote almost 99% identical to a paper that I might read in the past. I have done some exercise question that is related to the subject/theme in the exam as well as listen to zoom classes audio. I’m not a native English speaker and I used grammarly to help with my grammar and the program most of the time suggest me to rewrite what I wrote, concisely. I also grew up in a country that used ‘memorizing’ as a way to study and answers exam. The evidence clearly not on my side but I am not cheating. I state that I am not guilty although it’s highly unlikely that’s going to be the outcome. Am I doing the wrong thing?

Comment: Only one sentence??

Comment: What is a "closed and open book exam"?

Comment: @Part-timeEngineer yes only one sentence from the whole paper I assume

Comment: @FedericoPoloni the exam has a closed book section and open book section. We need to answer the closed book first before we can access the open book one

Comment: Did you write that sentence in the closed or open book part of the exam?

Comment: Isn't the goal of an exam to see if you have mastered a subject that was developed by people before you? Is one supposed to give references to previous work in an exam?  How can you not plagiarise during an exam? As written by the OP that seems like a strange accusation. There must be more to it.

Comment: @silvado in the closed book one

Comment: @Oбжорoв I do wrote a name of the author I remember (not only one but I guess total like 5 or 6) doing an important research in other questions. But I don’t usually remember the date just the name because they always comes up in classes and consider really important. In the closed book I never wrote a reference because I don’t know what paper or textbook my answer comes out from specifically. We do summarizing one or two book chapter every week for reading material.

Comment: Did you use Grammarly during the closed book part of the exam? Does your professor allow you to use Grammarly during the closed book part of the exam? Is the sentence one that Grammarly rewrote for you?

Comment: @Oбжорoв " How can you not plagiarise during an exam" This does not make sense

Comment: @shoover Grammarly wasn’t prohibited although they didn’t state it.  I clarify that and they said it was ok. On the last part, I run all of my paragraphs in grammarly. However, I don’t have the document anymore (on the grammarly) and my raw draft some in my native language and they say I can just translate it from English.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- you mean every exam you did was original work or if you used known results you always give a full citation? Wow, I am truly impressed.

Comment: No, that's not what plagiarism means.

Comment: To be clear, was this exam taken by distance/online/at home (as opposed to proctored in-person at the school)?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins it is taking home tests. Which is why I am in the disadvantage situation. I wish it’s proctored.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing the wrong thing?

Assuming your characterisation is honest and complete, it would seem that the university is overreacting.  If you have studied by reading books and papers, and then in a closed-book exam write a sentence that is almost identical to a sentence from those books or papers, I wouldn't consider that cheating or plagiarism.  I've never seen an exam where one is required to cite sources, and exam answers are not a publication, so I'm not sure if one even can plagiarise when answering questions on an exam.

If their evidence of cheating relies on one sentence that is very similar to a sentence from a book or paper, defend yourself.  One sentence is not much.  It is reasonably possible that you have read the sentence, that it is an obvious way of formulating it, and that you subconsciously came up with the formulation you had already read, during the exam.  Bring that up as your defence.

I hope that the university will not bring serious consequences based on what seems to be rather thin evidence.  Defend yourself, because a "conviction" of plagiarism or cheating may impact you negatively for a long time to come.

Comment: I am not sure when is the follow up information or any meeting going to happen. I probably need an obudsman  ? I don’t really know who’s to contact before and after the talk with my advisor I feel like he think I did cheat which makes me really sad. At that time (we talk) neither me and my advisor know which questions are the prof accused me for. I do bring my scramble notes and draft in words that I used during my exam to the meeting. I do have another one in one note as well but I didn’t shown that one.